# I need to find highest voters in each year Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one table lets say ranking info which has

```
username   mvid  votedate
john        1    23-sep-90
john        2    23-sep-90
smith       1    23-sep-90
john        3    24-oct-91
smith       3    24-oct-91
smith       4    25-dec-91
smith       5    25-dec-91
```

I need to write a sql query in sqldeveloper(Oracle) which will give me the member who has given the largest number of votes in each year. Output should be username,year, total number of votes in each year.
Lets consider the above example:
I need a output like this.

```
username  year  number_Of_Votes
john       1990    2
smith      1991    3
```

because in 1990 john beat smith by 1 vote while in 1991 smith beat john by 2 votes.

I get to the point where I counted all the votes but I could not get the maximum number of votes in a year.

This is what I have done:

```
select r1.username, 
    Extract(year from r1.votedate)"Year",
    count(username)
from rankinginfo r1
where Extract(year from r1.votedate)  is not null
group by Extract(year from r1.votedate), 
      r1.username;
order by  Extract(year from r1.votedate),
      username;
```

Comment: If for some reason you want to delete your own post, please click the `delete` button found below the post instead of removing the contents of the post. Thanks.

Comment: I rolled back your edit. If you want to delete the question, do so. Removing the content is not how StackOverflow works. If you need more information about how it does, you should review the [faq] and [about] pages, or check [meta].

Answer (score 5):

```
select  *
from    (
        select  VotesPerUserPerYear.*
        ,       dense_rank() over (
                    partition by voteyear
                    order by votecount desc) as rn
        from    (
                select  username
                ,       extract(year from votedate) as voteyear
                ,       count(*) as votecount
                from    YourTable
                group by
                        username
                ,       extract(year from votedate)
                ) VotesPerUserPerYear
        ) SubQueryWithRank
where   rn = 1 -- Only top voter per year
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bde47/9/0)

Comment: In that case you can use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`.  I've updated the answer and added an example to SQL Fiddle

Answer (score 2):

One way is

```
select username, year, cnt from (
select username, cnt, row_number() over (partition by year order by cnt desc) rn
from (
select username, to_char( votedate, 'YYYY' ) year, count(*) cnt
from rankinginfo
group by to_char( votedate, 'YYYY' )
)
) where rn = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try the below one:

```
SELECT MAX(point) as HIGHEST

FROM
(SELECT pointA as point FROM tableA

UNION
SELECT pointB as point FROM tableB) t
```